# iOS / iPhone - setting the color of an arbitrary row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to set the color of the selected row in a UITableView, using this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

The problem is, it's setting the color on all the rows. Furthermore, when I do select a specific row, it highlights that row in blue.  How do I get it to just highlight the selected row, in red?

Comment: Check `indexPath.row` to make sure it is the correct row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way  to me is to subclass `UITableViewCell` and overwrite the `setSelected:` method (leave everything else the same if you need to)

some sample code from an old project:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.916 green:.9648 blue:.9844 alpha:1.0];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = bg;
    [bg release];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Comment: That looks good - but how to I get it to be invoked by the UITableViewController? Also, is it invoked only on the data load?

Comment: Great - that worked. My next question will be how to set the color of a non-selected row, but this covers the selected one.